# Split and reformat Date column in R

Tags: r, date, time, split

I have a CSV file that I open using the `read.csv()` function.

It has 3 columns, *Id*, *Time* and *Value*.

The *Time* column is formatted like this: `4/12/2016 7:21:00 AM`

### First

What I want is to split it into *Date* `4/12/2016` and *Time* `7:21:00`

### Second

Convert the *Time* into 24 hours format instead of AM and PM.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split you can use str_split() from the library(stringr)

```
my_var <- str_split(string = my_df$Time, pattern = " ", n = 2, simplify = TRUE)

my_df$Date <- my_var[, 1] #In this column you'll find the Date
my_df$Time <- my_var[, 2] #In this column you'll find the Time
```

Answer (score 0):

`lubridate` is your friend (along with `hms` package). First convert your `Time` variable into a datetime object, then use helper functions to parse out the Date and Time. `lubridate` uses the 24hour format (POSIXIt) when it parses it.

```
my_df %>%
  mutate(Time = mdy_hms(Time),
         Date = as_date(Time),
         Time = hms::as_hms(Time))
```